# Django2.1 : Queryset ModelChoice in a ModelForm then save two forms

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-2.0

I want the current logged in user to be able to create and save both forms. The second form has a ManyToManyField and ForeignKey relationships as you can see below.

Currently I have tried to queryset the current user from `ChatGroupUser` ModelForm.

With the current codes, as soon as I try to access the page, Django raise the error below:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

it says that the error comes from line 88, which is:

```
form_user = ChatGroupUserForm()
```

## Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_fun4/Groupixx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_fun4/Groupixx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_fun4/Groupixx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_fun4/Groupixx/groupixx/core/views.py", line 88, in create_group
    form_user = ChatGroupUserForm()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

## models.py

```
class ChatGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    group_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_group_admins')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    is_current = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

class ChatGroupUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    chat_group = models.ForeignKey(ChatGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_group_users')
```

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class ChatGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatGroup
        fields = ['name',]

class ChatGroupUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatGroupUser
        fields = ['user']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChatGroupUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(user=user)
```

## views.py

```
def create_group(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_group = ChatGroupForm(request.POST)
        form_user = ChatGroupUserForm(request.POST)

        if form_group.is_valid():
            create_form = form_group.save(commit=False)
            create_form.group_admin = request.user
            create_form.save()
            form_user.save(commit=False)
            form_user.user = user
            form_user.save()
            return redirect('core:group_list')

    else:
        form_group = ChatGroupForm()
        form_user = ChatGroupUserForm()

    context = {
            'form_group':form_group,
            'form_user': form_user
    }
    return render(request, 'core/create-group.html', context)
```

I would appreciate any help, I am not sure why django is throwing an error and why i am not able to create and save both forms.

Answer (score 2):

it is because your `init` function has parameter `user`,
while your view didn't pass the `user`.

here's how to fix it
in your view:
`form_user = ChatGroupUserForm(user=request.user)`

then in your form:

```
class ChatGroupUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatGroupUser
        fields = ['user']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ChatGroupUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

hope it works :)